# Matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to create an ABC logo and animate it with matplotlib, I have got all the phases by changing the delta index I am able to get all x and y coordinates but I am not able to animate from one phase to another .below is the link of what I am trying to do.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sL0FhqGtV4U&ab_channel=AustralianTelevisionArchive

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


fig = plt.figure()
axis = plt.axes(xlim =(-110, 110),
                ylim =(-110, 110))
delta = [0, 3.14 / 8, 3.14 / 4, 3 * 3.14 / 8, 3.14 / 2, 5 * 3.14 / 8, 3 * 3.14 / 8, 7 * 3.14 / 8, 3.14]

def dS(delta):
    A = 100
    B = 100
    a = 1
    b = 3
    # delta = 3.14/4
    t = 0
    sinVals = []
    cosVals = []
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        t += 0.01
        # Apply Lissajous Parametric Equations
        sinVals.append(A * math.sin(a * t + delta))
        cosVals.append(B * math.sin(b * t))
    return sinVals,cosVals
    
sinVals,cosVals=deltaShift.dS(delta[1])


line, = axis.plot(sinVals, cosVals)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will produce what you want

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


pi = np.pi
deltas = np.linspace(0,8,32) / pi

def dS(delta):
    
    A = 100
    B = 100
    a = 1
    b = 3
    # delta = 3.14/4
    t = 0
    sinVals = []
    cosVals = []
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        t += 0.01
        # Apply Lissajous Parametric Equations
        sinVals.append(A * math.sin(a * t + delta))
        cosVals.append(B * math.sin(b * t))
    return sinVals,cosVals
    
def make_plot(delta):
    
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(-110, 110)
    ax.set_ylim(-110, 110)
    sinVals,cosVals=dS(delta)
    line, = ax.plot(sinVals, cosVals)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, make_plot, deltas, blit = False)
ani.save('test.gif', writer='pillow', fps=16)
```

The output gif file is

[image: gif]

Comment: @akshaylalwani please accept this answer if it resolves your problem :)